# Why wont text-align:center; work in this case?

Tags: css

I noticed in the inspector my text-align:center; is crossed out for "span#artlink" --it works on all my other links but not this one, I was curious if anyone can figure out why this is the case.

Thank you

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>

            <div id="mainnav">
                <span id="home"><a href="index.html">MARK LOVATO</a></span>
                <span id="vidlink"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></span>
                <span id="artlink"><a href="art.html">ART</a></span>
                <span id="motionlink"><a href="motion">MOTION</a></span>
                <span id="reellink"><a href="reel.html">REEL</a></span>
                <span id="aboutlink"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></span>
            </div>
        </header>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
    a:link {text-decoration:none;}

    span#home{width:100%; height:50px; float:left; clear:both;}

    span#home,span#home a{color:#ffffff; background-color:#000000; 
    font- family:helvetica; font-weight:600;font-size:43px; letter-spacing:2px; 
text-align:center; font-stretch:semi-condensed;}
    span#home:hover, span#home:hover a{color:; background-color:;}

    span#vidlink{width:65%; height:50px; float:left;}
    span#vidlink,
    span#vidlink a{ color:#000000; background-color:#ffffff;text-align:center;
    font-weight:350; font-size:43px; letter-spacing:10px;}
    span#vidlink:hover, span#vidlink:hover a{color:#ffffff; background-color:#000000;}

    span#artlink{width:35%; height:50px; float:right;}

    span#artlink,span#artlink a{color:#acacac; background-color:#555555;
    text-align:center; font-weight:200; font-size:42px; letter-spacing:15px;}
    span#artlink:hover,span#artlink:hover a{color:#ff7dbd; background-color:#d60a70;}
```

Comment: It appears to be centered and working for me in chrome. Here is a fiddle with it working, directly from you code: [text-align center fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrCord/ENkqn/)

Comment: Weird, i am also using chrome and it does not look like that, to me Art is right against the left side of the div, do know why it would possibly look different for me?

Comment: @user1905577, does that happen with the jsfiddle, or with the exact code you posted, without any additional CSS? It sounds like there would be some other style sheet causing the issue.

Comment: @user1905577: yes, please confirm that either 1. the fiddle I posted does not work for you, or 2. that the fiddle does work but your code on your server/machine is not working? If #2 it means that additional code in your project is actually the problem.

Comment: I only have one style sheet so far, in jsfiddle it looks the way i want it to look, but in the editor im using when i open it in chrome the text-align tag is crossed out (in the inspector tool)